# 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined' Redis connections

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, redis, azure-redis-cache

I am trying to connect to a Redis Azure instance and I'm following the tutorial here [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-nodejs-get-started#create-a-new-nodejs-app). However I keep receiving this error

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined"

on this line

> bluebird.promisifyAll(redis.RedisClient.prototype);

I am using nodeJS on VSCode. I have npm installed redis and bluebird. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Seems like this tutorial was written when v3.1.2 (of node-redis) was the latest version, try to `npm install redis@v3.1.2`

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the "redis-adapter" of npm.